Spinnaker Application not Creating
I have a kubernetes cluster on a VPS and I have also setup Spinnaker:

I have Halyard installed on the Debian machine
configured hal to use personal registry with Docker registry config using ADDRESS=hub.mydomain.com etc. as cloud provider
I am using the local Debian as my environment since I can't use the configure provider account for a distributed installation on kubernetes
I have minio as storage service and I created access/secret key to be used by Halyard
I do have authentication in place with G Suite
And I have deployed Halyard sudo hal deploy apply and connected sudo hal deploy apply but whenever I try to create an application, it just get stuck without creating it with no error logs as shown in the image.

I have checked the logs files in /var/log/spinnaker but no logs.
Any help with this setup?
